# Minimum of $L^2$-functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f\in L^2$. I need to show that

$$
\min_{c\in \mathbb{R}}\parallel f-c\parallel_2=\parallel f-m\parallel_2 
$$  for $$m=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

My idea starts with this:
$$
\parallel f-c\parallel_2=\int_a^b(f-c)^2dx = \parallel f\parallel_2^2 - 2 \langle f,c\rangle + \parallel c\parallel_2^2-2 = \parallel f\parallel_2^2-2\int_a^bfdx \cdot c + (b-a)c^2
$$
Now it is clear that this is a quadratic polynomial, but how can I show that $c=m$ is it's minimum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the function $$I(c)=\int\limits_a^b (f(x))^2\, dx-2c\int\limits_a^b f(x)\, dx+(b-a)c^2.$$ Taking the derivative, you get that $$I'(c)=-2\int\limits_a^b f(x)\, dx+2(b-a)c.$$ This is zero whenever $$c=\frac{1}{b-a}\int\limits_a^b f(x)\, dx,$$ so this $c$ is a critical point. Checking the sign of the second derivative guarantees that this is a minimum (the second derivative is strictly positive).

Hence, $c=m.$

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot. So I guess the first part doesn't matter any longer, I mean $\parallel f-c\parallel_2^2$ because we are "Interested" in $c$ right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you're asking if your original work is needed, then the answer is yes. We compute $\|f-c\|_2^2,$ then do calculus on it. In particular, $I(c)=\|f-c\|_2^2.$ The general idea is to call $I(c)=\|f-c\|_2^2,$ compute the right-hand side, then do the calculus needed to find the minimum.

Comment: Thank you again. I'm just wondering why in your analysis $\parallel f\parallel_2^2$ is no longer "looked at". I should have explained my question better.

Comment: Oh, typo, thanks! But you are correct in your first comment, they vanish when taking the derivative, so they don't affect anything.

Comment: Yes, exactly! $\ $

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much.